# dojo display property

Tags: dojo

I am trying to assign the anything value to the display property as shown below.

```
dojo.query(".item").style('display', 'anything');
```

But it is not effecting. Please provide me any suggestion.

Comment: Well, `display` can't be `anything`. It has to be one of `block none inline inline-block`

Comment: But otherwise that is syntactically correct. So unless you don't have any elements with `class='item'` it should work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have to give the `.item` a display setting in CSS before you can change the setting in the script.

So, if you do `.item { display:none; }` in CSS,

`query('.item').style('display', 'block');` in the script will work.

This is how Dojo works for me.

On a side note, consider looking at Dojo 1.7 where you don't use the `dojo.method` way of coding.